# Replacing '=' with '==' in a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string such as `'x = 1'` and I want to be able to replace all occurances of a single `'='` character with `'=='`.  However if given the string `'x == 1'` I want to leave it as it is.  The string can also not be expected to be perfectly formatted, `'x =1' '1=x' and 'x=   1'` are all valid inputs.

I cannot use `string.replace('=', '==')` as it will turn the `'x == 1'` string into `'x ==== 1'`

I tried using regular expressions and look ahead with `re.sub(r'=(?!=)', '==', string)` however for the string `'x == 1'` this produces `'x === 1'`, as the look ahead does not consume the second = so the regex proceeds to find and replace it after it ignores the first =.

Does anyone know of a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: you could use `string.replace(' = ', ' == ')`

Comment: if you look, there are spaces around the equals signs

Comment: Reread his comment.  He's suggesting replacing `' = '`, an equals sign bracketed by white space.  This method would only be problematic if you needed to change `'x=1'` to `'x==1'` because in this case, the `=` isn't bracketed by whitespace.  But changing `'x = 1'` into `'x == 1'` will work just fine.

Comment: there will not always be spaces around an = sign, the string can not be expected to be perfectly formatted like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With just negative look-ahead, the 2nd `=` will satisfy the regex, and will be replaced with `==`.

You have to use both look-ahead and look-behind:

```
re.sub(r'(?<!=)=(?!=)', '==', string)
```

Comment: `16` seconds difference :)

Comment: @Sniffer Your computation seems a little off.

Comment: 34 seconds is a lot : After I typed my answer, before I hit enter, I had the time to see Rohit's answer appear, read it to check mine was still useful, conclude it would have been identical, and thus decide to drop it, all this before I saw yours appear.

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I needed, I completely forgot about lookbehind as an option.

Comment: @RohitJain... I'd give you the answer, but apparently you answered too fast, I need to wait 8 minutes before I can do that.

Comment: @dystroy LOL, Great answer Rohit ;)

Comment: This is why I love StackOverflow... simple issue that I am having a brain fart on and within half a minute there's already 3 people trying to answer my question! You guys are awesome.

Comment: @EEP Why didn't you accept this ? You could have done it at least one minute ago. That's a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
 re.sub(r'(?<!=)=(?!=)', '==', string)
```

Comment: So close +1 still for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

Non-regex:

```
s.replace('==', '=').replace('=', '==')
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
string.replace('=', '==')
```

Followed by:

```
string.replace('====', '==')
```

Comment: this works if you can guarantee that never in the future will `====` be valid. Or `===================================` for that matter. Which may actually be the case in some comments, or strings within your program.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your inputs are done "nicely" and are all `foo[space]=[space]bar`, with spaces surrounding the `=`, then put those spaces into your string replacement:

```
string.replace(' = ', ' == ');
                ^-^--  ^--^-- spaces
```

If you do have variable inputs, e.g. `foo= bar` or `foo =bar`, then you'll need the regex version, or lots of extra substring manipulation to check for preceeding/following characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use

```
string.replace('=', '==')
string.replace('====', '==')
```

which I find more readable. I don't know how it compares performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=(?:\b|\s))=(?=(?:\b|\s))', '==', string)
```

`\b` matches word boundaries, so it won't match when there's an adjacent `=`.

[Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/OclQrF265J)

Comment: See the Rubular link.

Comment: @Barmar see this rubular link...  http://www.rubular.com/r/8JeYt6A9IN it doesn't match the `x = 5` condition.

Comment: Fixed that, although now my answer isn't as concise as some of the others.